# Data Not posted to sanity backend using createdIfNotExist and google Auth

Tags: reactjs, sanity

trying to post data to sanityBanckend Using the CreateIfNotExist method but to no avail

I have been able to configure the Google Auth to work perfectly fine and also get the required data in my console but I noticed that it is not being posted to the sanity backend

```
const responseGoogle = (response: any) =\> {
localStorage.setItem(
"user",
JSON.stringify(jwt_decode(response.credential))
);

      try {
        const decode: { name: string; picture: string; sub: string } = jwt_decode(
          response.credential
        );
        const { name, picture, sub } = decode;
        const doc = {
          _id: sub,
          _type: "users",
          userName: name,
          image: picture,
        };
        
        client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
          navigate("/", { replace: true });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log({error})
      }

};
```